# Geography information

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an application which uses geography informations.
I don't want to implement this feature because I think I could find a free services which provides needed informations to me.

Anybody can help me which service I could use?

(Geography information means country, county, town data.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html)

The "Geocode" feature allows you to pass it any Address and it will figure out the Latitude/Longitude for you!
Then you can later use the Lat/Long to generate a Map with a Marker on that point.